# Detect Errors in JSContext

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
JSValue *val = [context evaluateScript:@"var num = 5 + 5;\nnum = 6"];
NSLog(@"%d", [context[@"num"] toInt32]);
```

This code still outputs 6, so I'm wondering how to detect errors in Javascript code (there should be a semi-colon after the 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolons are not required after each line in javascript

See this article for more information: http://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/